# How can I get the first image from each album with an even ID in React using Fetch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I have an API that returns 5000 images. I want to get the first image from each album with an even ID in React using Fetch.

The problem is can't figure out how to filter the data to get the ones with the even IDs and the First Image of the even ID albums.

[image]

[image]

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

// Import Materials from Material-ui
import {Grid} from '@material-ui/core';


const Album = () => {
    const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
    const [imagesCount, setImagesCount] = useState(10);
    const api = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos';

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(api)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
          const filterData = data.filter(x => x.albumId % 2 === 0);
          for(const url of filterData) {
            if(url.albumId % 2 === 0) {
              // How to get only the first even ablumID url of each even albumID?
            }
          }
          setImages(filterData);
          console.log(filterData);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))

      }, []);

    return (
        <div>
        <Grid container spacing={3} alignItems="center">
          {images.map((album) => (
            <Grid item key={album.id} xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
              <img className="albumImg" src={album.url} alt={album.title} />
            </Grid>
          ))}
        </Grid>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Album;
```

Comment: So what is the issue that you’re running into? By the way, `Array.prototype.filter` returns a new array and doesn’t mutate the old array, so if you want to call `setImages` on the filtered array, then you should store that new array in a variable and use that to set your `state`.

Comment: data.filter(x => x.albumId % 2 === 0) is not really filtering anything.

Comment: See my updated comment.

Comment: data.filter(x => x.albumId % 2 === 0); are you trying to filter ids that are even numbers or are you trying ti get id===0?

Comment: I'm trying to filter IDs that have even numbers.

Comment: Did you try what I suggested?

Comment: As @goto1 said you need to assign the result of that filter. `data = data.filter(x => x.albumId % 2 === 0);` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: @goto1 I did what you suggested by adding to a constant - `const filterData = data.filter(x => x.albumId % 2 === 0);` and the i added to setImages, nothing changed. I'm still getting 5000 albums unfiltered.

Comment: I have updated my code in my question

Comment: This should definitely do the trick - it works on my end. What do you get when you `console.log(data.length)` versus `console.log(filteredData.length)`?

Comment: @goto1 that definitely did the trick! I was looking at the log from data, not filterData, oppps, thanks tho. Now how can I get only the first image from every even album?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, you’re saying an array of `url`s? Is that what you want for the `images` array?

Comment: Yes, I want to get the first URL of every first even array. So the first image URL from albumId 2 and 4 and 6 and so on.. but only the first image from every even albumId

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the first issue, `Array.prototype.filter` does not mutate the existing array but instead returns a new array with the elements that pass the test, so you need to  store that new array in a variable and use that to update your state,

```js
const api = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos";

fetch(api)
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    const filterData = data.filter((x) => x.albumId % 2 === 0);

    console.log("original", data.length);
    console.log("filtered", filterData.length);
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

As for your second issue, if you want to create a new array with items that have unique `albumId`s, you could use `Array.prototype.reduce` to loop through all items and only add those that are not already in the `accumulator`,

```js
const api = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos";

fetch(api)
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    const filterData = data.filter((x) => x.albumId % 2 === 0);
    const uniqueItems = filterData.reduce((accumulator, item) => {
      const isDuplicateItem = accumulator.find(
        (i) => i.albumId === item.albumId
      );
      // append the item if there's no existing
      // item in the array with the same `albumId`
      if (!isDuplicateItem) {
        return [...accumulator, item];
      }

      return accumulator;
    }, []);

    console.log("uniqueItems", uniqueItems.length);
    console.log(uniqueItems[0]);
    console.log(uniqueItems[1]);
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

See more if needed:

- [Array.prototype.reduce - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: But how can I get only the first array of each even array?

Comment: @Rastezzy can you clarify what you mean by “first array of each even array”? You’re iterating over an array of objects with the following properties: `{albumId: number, id: number, title: string, url: string, thumbnailUrl: string}`. What is the `array` that you’re speaking of?

Comment: Sorry for the poor use of terms, I meant objects. Now since we have multiple objects with similar albumId's, I simply need the URL from the first albumId of the first even number only. So the first url from the first object with albumId 2 only and not the rest with albumId 2, and so on.. does that makes sense?

Comment: I have updated my code, this the closest I could get to the answer.

Comment: @Rastezzy see my edit - I think that’s what you’re looking for.

Comment: @Rastezzy I just realized, it’s supposed to be `filterData.reduce` rather than `data.reduce` - you want the unique `albumIds` only for those with even numbers, so I made an edit, but you get the idea.

Comment: I did that already in my code, yeah I got the idea.

Comment: I haven't done that, I don't know why but I will re-mark it.

Answer (score 0):

Its a late answer but i will post is in case other come across,
I think i have more simple solution, where we do not need to use high order array methods like filter()
all i did is using a loop and jump in steps of 50, hence we know each album have 50 image

here is the code

```
// get photos form the apiURl {https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos}
function getPhotos() {
console.log('Get Photos Called');
fetch(apiURl)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => sortPhotos(data));
}

// sort photos from  the api fetch
function sortPhotos(data) {
//  Sorted Objects saved in result
const result = [];

for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index += 50) {
  result.push(data[index]);     
}
```